# MPI_Comm_spawn fails with "All nodes which are allocated for this job are already filled"

Tags: c++, openmpi, pbs, qsub, torque

I'm trying to use Torque's (5.1.1) qsub command to launch multiple OpenMPI 
processes, one process per node, and having each process launch a single 
process on its *own* *local* node using MPI_Comm_spawn().  MPI_Comm_spawn() is reporting:

```
All nodes which are allocated for this job are already filled.
```

My OpenMPI version is 4.0.1.

I am following the instructions here to control the mapping of nodes.

[Controlling node mapping of MPI_COMM_SPAWN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47743425/controlling-node-mapping-of-mpi-comm-spawn)

using the --map-by ppr:1:node option to mpiexec, and a hostfile (programatically derived 
from the ${PBS_NODEFILE} file that Torque produces).  My derived file MyHostFile looks 
like this:

```
n001.cluster.com slots=2 max_slots=2
n002.cluster.com slots=2 max_slots=2
```

while the original ${PBS_NODEFILE} only has the node names, and no slot specifications.

My qsub command is

```
qsub -V -j oe -e ./tempdir -o ./tempdir  -N MyJob   MyJob.bash
```

The mpiexec command from MyJob.bash is

```
mpiexec --display-map --np 2 --hostfile MyNodefile --map-by ppr:1:node <executable>.
```

MPI_Comm_spawn() causes this error to be printed:

```
Data for JOB [22220,1] offset 0 Total slots allocated 1   <=====

 ========================   JOB MAP   ========================

 Data for node: n001    Num slots: 1    Max slots: 0    Num procs: 1
        Process OMPI jobid: [22220,1] App: 0 Process rank: 0 Bound: socket 0[core 0[hwt 0]]:[B/././././././././.][./././././././././.]

 =============================================================

All nodes which are allocated for this job are already filled.
```

There are two things that occur to me:
(1) "Total slots allocated" is 1 above, but I need at least two slots available. 
(2) It may not be right to try to specify a hostfile to mpiexec when 
using Torque (though it is  derived from the Torque hostfile ${PBS_NODEFILE}).  Maybe my derived hostfile is being ignored.

Is there a way to make this work?    I've tried recompiling OpenMPI 
without Torque support, hopefully preventing OpenMPI from interacting 
with it, but it didn't change the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question: adding the argument **-l nodes=1:ppn=2** to the qsub command reserves 2 processors on the node, even though mpiexec is launching only one process.  MPI_Comm_spawn() can then spawn the new process on the second reserved slot.

I also had to compile OpenMPI without Torque support, since including it causes my hostfile argument to be ignored and the Torque-generated hostfile to be used.